# Open a Virtual Keyboard through Java fx Program in Cent OS 7

Tags: java, linux, javafx, centos7

I have created a sample program using Java FX that contains one textbox.  The deployment target is Linux CentOS 7 64 bit . I need to display virtual keyboard that support Japaneses text input since the machine has only touch screen display. No Keyboard is attached.

The aim is to open a virtual keyboard using Java program. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe check this repo for inspiration : https://github.com/PankajPrakashh/On-Screen-Keyboard/tree

You should be able to combine awt with javafx (or rewrite your own keyboard with javafx).

Another solution is to install a native application on the os.

Comment: Package to install under linux for native solution : onboard

Comment: Does the linux kde have built in Virtual keyboard?

Comment: We finally decided to use the Florence keyboard. thanks